# Inserting Multiple Documents into MongoDB while Requiring Unique Index

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My collection `P` has a unique index on the `phone` field:

```
db.P.ensureIndex( { phone: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )
db.P.insert( {phone:"555-1234"} )
```

If I insert an array of documents, where even one document has a duplicate key:

```
db.P.insert( [{phone:"911"},{phone:"555-1234"}] )
> E11000 duplicate key error index: test.P.$phone_1  dup key: { : "555-1234" }
```

The entire insert fails, and the valid number is not inserted.

**Question:** How can I do bulk inserts, make sure the valid documents are inserted, and get information on which inserts failed? *Bonus points for showing code with the nodejs api.*

Comment: When I last tried it, it wasn't possible.

Comment: I believe you'll need to insert each document individually right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB drivers have a "ContinueOnError" option that would cause mongo to skip records with duplicate unique keys.  As far as identifying what was skipped, per documentation: "If multiple errors occur during a bulk insert, clients only receive the last error generated. (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/).

For Node.js, it would be something like

```
db.P.insert( [{phone:"911"},{phone:"555-1234"}], {continueOnError:true} )
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#insert

Comment: I had found this documentation, but confusingly it does *not* work on the mongo shell, but *does* work from nodejs. Thanks!